# JQuery - fadeIn using variable instead of id?

Tags: jquery, fadein

This code works:

```
$(contentDiv).fadeIn("slow");
```

This does not:

```
var elementName = 'contentDiv';
$(elementName).fadeIn("slow");
```

No fade effect appears.

I'm about to feel like an idiot with this solution I know but I can't work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify whether 'contentDiv' is a *class* or *id*

```
var elementName = '.contentDiv';
$(elementName).fadeIn("slow");
```

OR

```
var elementName = '#contentDiv';
$(elementName).fadeIn("slow");
```

Answer (score 1):

If `"contentDiv"` is the `name` of your element then you need to use:

```
$("[name=" + elementName + "]").fadeIn("slow");
```

If it's the `id` then you need to use:

```
$("#" + elementName).fadeIn("slow");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepend your string with the rest of the selector. If `contentDiv` is an `id`, that would be a `#`:

```
$("#" + elementName").fadeIn("slow");
```

If it is actually a value of a `name` attribute you would need to insert it into an [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$("[name='" + elementName + "']").fadeIn("slow");
```

If `contentDiv` is something else (a class perhaps), you need to change the selector appropriately. The section on [selectors in the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) would be a good place to start.

What you currently have will look for an element of type "contentDiv", which is not what you want:

```
<contentDiv>This is an invalid element...</contentDiv>
```

Answer (score 1):

`contentDiv` is not a tag/element. You are forgetting to specify an `id` or `class` to your selector:

```
var elementName = '#contentDiv';
```

Or

```
var elementName = '.contentDiv';
```

depending on whether you use a `class` or `id` for your div(s).

Answer (score 1):

```
var elementName = '#contentDiv';
$(elementName).fadeIn("slow");
```

`#` is the reason.

Answer (score 1):

> This code works:
>
> $(contentDiv).fadeIn("slow");

It should not work unless *you are using Internet Explorer*. IE has a nasty habit of creating variables for HTML elements that have an ID. (EDIT: chrome seems to do that too).

The connect way is:

```
var elementName = "contentDiv";
$("#" + elementName).fadeIn("slow");
```